# Service Vs rxjs Store in angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs

Is Store replacing the Services in angular 6.

1. For storing the global data.
2. For storing common hierarchical data.
3. Inter-component communication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No **Store** is not for replacing **services** in Angular.

In fact store needs services to make HTTP calls(through effects), which is a very common use case.

There are lots of articles on the internet talking about why you should use Store (and why you should NOT). I would recommend do a little Google search and check them out.

But generally speaking Store not only storing data but also manipulate it nicely through strict rules so that when your app grows, it prevents you from messing it up.

Whereas services open the data to everyone to access. So it's more difficult for you to stop yourself (or your colleagues) to write unmaintainable code. After all we are just human and human make mistakes. So sometimes it's nice to have those little rules to make ourselves more disciplined.

In theory, everything Store can do, can also be done by plain services (just `BehaviourSubject`), although you need to write those "rules" yourself. But... why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You mean ngrx store.

ngrx store assists with:

(1) Storing app data

(2) Storing UI data

(3) Caching

(4) Very early initialisation, before any components are loaded you can start sending HTTP requests for data

(5) Inter-component communication

You can fully integrate with the store, which could, depending on your app, remove the need for services or you could do a partial integration and retain some services as best fits your architecture.